# How can I calculate the average of a column in bash?

Tags: bash, shell

I have a file.txt with the structure `Code;Name;sur;Sur2;CLASS;N1;N2;N3`.

I want to test if the `CLASS` exists, and if it exists then calculate the average of `N1;`, then the average of `N2;`, then of `N3`, and finally add an option to see all together. That last option is easy with a sum of the three column averages.

This is what I've got so far

```
while :; do
    echo -n "Enter a valid CLASS code"
    read codigo
    [ -n "$codigo" ] || continue
    awk -F';' -v c="$codigo" '$5 == c {f=5;next}1;END{exit(f?0:1)}' \
        agenda.txt > agenda.out && break
done

opc1=0

while test "$opc1" !="1"; do
    echo "Check N1(S/N): "
    read opc1
    case $opc1 in
        S|s)
            columaula=`cat agenda.txt | cut -d";" -f6`
            cat agenda.txt | awk '{ total += $columaula; count++ } END { printf "%.0f",total/count }'
            pausa
            ;;
        N|n)
            break ;;
        *)
            echo -n "Por favor elige una opción válida"
            pausa
            ;;
    esac
done
```

Comment: sample data file and desired output will help to get more answers.  Also, if your code doesn't work as desired pointing out what is missing or wrong will help as well.

Comment: Suggestion: Though coding this in pure bash (plus bc for float average maybe) should be possible, you should really got for `awk`.